# Use rowspan and colspan

Tags: html, angularjs

I have a table like this:

[image]

I want to add in my cellule two button like this

[image]

How can I use rowspan and colspan for this? For reference I have created [a Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mba8g4L2/).

My HTML code:

```
<table ng-controller="PropertiesCompareCtrl" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
    <tr class="warning">
        <th>Key</th>
        <th>Valeur version {{application.version}}</th>
        <th></th>
        <th>Valeur version {{applicationCible.version}}</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody ng-repeat="group in properties.groups">
    <tr>
        <td class="danger" colspan="4" ng-click="hideGroup = !hideGroup">
            <a href="" ng-click="group.$hideRows = !group.$hideRows">
                <span class="glyphicon" ng-class="{ 'glyphicon-chevron-right': group.$hideRows, 'glyphicon-chevron-down': !group.$hideRows }"></span>
                <strong>{{group.name}}</strong>
            </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="member in group.members" ng-hide="hideGroup">
        <td>{{ member.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ member.valueRef }}</td>
        <td >

        </td>
        <td>{{ member.valueCible }}</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use buttons in one cell:

```
<td>
    <button></button><br>
    <button></button>
</td>
```

or use [`ng-repeat-start` + `ng-repeat-end`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) and `rowspan="2"`:

```
<tr ng-repeat-start="member in group.members" ng-hide="hideGroup">
    <td rowspan="2">{{ member.name }}</td>
    <td rowspan="2">{{ member.valueRef }}</td>
    <td>
        <button></button>
    </td>
    <td rowspan="2">{{ member.valueCible }}</td>
</tr>
<tr ng-repeat-end ng-hide="hideGroup">
    <td>
        <button></button>
    </td>
</tr>
```